# How to get AppDomainSetup.SetConfigurationBytes() working?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, appdomainsetup

In my application I'm creating sandbox domain and I need dynamically define binding redirect rules. However I cannot pass neither ConfigurationFile setting nor raw xml data using SetConfigurationBytes method.

I created a sample to check if configuration data is applied to child domain:

```
var configData =
@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key='MyData' value='CUSTOM'/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>";
var setup = new AppDomainSetup {
ApplicationBase = runtimeAssembliesPath // ,ConfigurationFile = configFilePath
                };
setup.SetConfigurationBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configData));
var sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", evidence, setup);
var verifier = (Sample)_sandbox.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(thisAssemblyName, typeof(Sample).FullName);
verifier.DebugPrint();
```

where Verifier is plain class with one method:

```
public class Sample: MarshalByRefObject 
{
    public void DebugPrint()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("=====================================");
        Debug.Print("Reading config: =====|{0}|=====", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyData"]);
        Debug.WriteLine("=====================================");
    }
}
```

**Update**
The first issue with code above is that it must be inherited from MarshalByRefObject to marshal DebugPrint call to child appdomain instead of making call on copy created in current domain (thanks sthotakura).
As a result ConfigurationFile setting begins to work.However still no luck with SetConfigurationBytes. Anyway the goal was to define bindingRules which DOES work if passed via SetConfigurationBytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an object across `AppDomain` boundary, the class must be derived from `MarshalByRefObject`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Page:

> Types must inherit from MarshalByRefObject when the type is used
>   across application domain boundaries, and the state of the object must
>   not be copied because the members of the object are not usable outside
>   the application domain where they were created.

That means, your Sample Class should derive from `MarshalByRefObject`:

```
[Serializable]
public class Sample : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void DebugPrint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Reading config: =====|{0}|=====", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyData"]);
        Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
    }
}
```

I have tried in a sample app, but with a Config XML instead of calling `SetConfigurationData` and it works, Below is my Sample code for your reference:

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ConfigurationFile = "SandBoxConfig.xml";
var sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", null, setup);
var verifier = (Sample)sandbox.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Sample).FullName);
verifier.DebugPrint();
```

**EDIT**

From MSDN Page, [AppDomainSetup.SetConfigurationBytes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.setconfigurationbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Some consumers of configuration file information do not use the
>   information stored by the SetConfigurationBytes method. The runtime
>   does not enforce this. To ensure that all configuration file
>   information is replaced in a new application domain, use the
>   ConfigurationFile property to specify a configuration file. The
>   SetConfigurationBytes method does affect assembly binding.

So, I suspect, types in `System.Configuration` namespace (like `ConfigurationManager`) ignoring the configuration data provided via `SetConfigurationBytes`.

Comment: Good catch! I was just asking about SetConfigurationBytes().

Comment: @olegz Ok, so you want to replace bits of configuration for the new AppDomain, as oppose to providing a new configuration for the new appdomaiin?

Comment: @olegz looks like whatever is passed via SetConfigurationBytes is getting ignored :(

Comment: @olegz in your original question, you also mentioned you couldn't pass `ConfigurationFile` either, so this answer is an option for you.

Comment: ConfigurationFile does work, thank you. SetConfigurationBytes does not :)

Answer (score 0):

SetConfigurationBytes does work. I constructed an XDocument to represent the App.Config, as below

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<probing privatePath="TestProbingPath" />
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>

XDocument doc=as above
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(stream);
byte[] configBytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Note that stream.GetBuffer will not work.